# Can I use a modulo to specify an interval in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to list items that have not been updated for a multiple of two years after their last update. This is to run as a cron job once a day.

I know I can do this with something ugly like:

```
SELECT art_id, art_update FROM items 
WHERE art_update = now()::date - interval '2 years'
OR art_update = now()::date - interval '4 years'
OR art_update = now()::date - interval '6 years'
OR art_update = now()::date - interval '8 years'
OR art_update = now()::date - interval '10 years';
```

Is there any way to avoid this by checking for a modulo interval? Or some other generalised way to express this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a series of dates at 2 year intervals going back from today (to 10 years ago in the below) and join this back to your table:

```
SELECT i.art_id, i.art_update
FROM items i
    INNER JOIN generate_series(2, 10, 2) s (years)
        ON i.art_update = now()::date - interval '1 years' * s.years;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf9db/3)**

*N.B* This appears to be marginally faster if you generate the dates in the series, rather than numbers:

```
SELECT i.art_id, i.art_update
FROM items i
    INNER JOIN generate_series(now() - interval '10 years', 
                                now() - interval '2 years', 
                                interval '2 years') d (d)
        ON art_update = d.d::date;
```

Comment: That's spot on, thank you. I chose this rather than the answer by Clodoaldo Neto above because I prefer a join to a sub-query. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select art_id, art_update
from items 
where art_update in (
    (now() - interval '2 years')::date,
    (now() - interval '4 years')::date,
    (now() - interval '6 years')::date,
    (now() - interval '8 years')::date,
    (now() - interval '10 years')::date
);
```

or

```
select art_id, art_update
from items 
where art_update in (
    select d::date
    from generate_series (
        now() - interval '2 years',
        now() - interval '10 years',
        - interval '2 years'
    ) d(d)
);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT art_id, art_update
FROM items
    Where int4(date_part('year', art_update)) % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: This would return every day in 2004, 2006, 2008, 2010, and 2012. Not just the day that corresponds to today (e.g. 2010-03-06).